# External HDD is extremely slow in Debian

Tags: mount, external-hdd, troubleshooting

Mounting, listing files, copying files is exceptionally slow. It's a new 1TB unit, formatted as ext4. I do not suspect any physical damage. Copying is at 64kB/s. No entry at `/etc/fstab`. When Nautilus recognises it, I ask to mount it (throught the GUI).

`dmesg -w`

```
[1161163.747883] [drm:ironlake_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
[1161163.747977] [drm:ironlake_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
[1161239.160081] EXT4-fs (sdc1): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[1161240.725154] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[1161508.277827] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 37
[1161508.325809] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1161508.325817] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 3a 04 09 b8 00 00 20 00
[1161508.325821] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 973343160
[1161508.325864] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1161508.325868] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 09 80 09 00 00 00 10 00
[1161508.325870] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 159385856
[1161508.325876] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 19922976, lost async page write
[1161508.325887] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 19922977, lost async page write
[1161508.325912] Aborting journal on device sdc1-8.
[1161508.325954] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdc1-8.
[1161508.326801] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:962: inode #3670046: lblock 0: comm pool: error -5 reading directory block
[1161508.326819] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[1161508.326822] EXT4-fs (sdc1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[1161508.326824] EXT4-fs (sdc1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[1161508.327164] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:962: inode #3670042: lblock 0: comm pool: error -5 reading directory block
[1161508.327420] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:962: inode #3670039: lblock 0: comm pool: error -5 reading directory block
[1161508.328952] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[1161508.328991] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1161508.421624] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=28751 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[1161508.421645] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=758130 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[1161508.431967] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=28751 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[1161508.432028] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=758130 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[1161508.492581] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1463: inode #2: comm pool: reading directory lblock 0
[1161508.492618] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1463: inode #2: comm pool: reading directory lblock 0
[1161508.492648] EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:1463: inode #2: comm pool: reading directory lblock 0
[1161508.493091] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:962: inode #2: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[1161508.493126] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:962: inode #2: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[1161508.493153] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:962: inode #2: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[1161508.493178] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:962: inode #2: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[1161508.493204] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:962: inode #2: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[1161508.493229] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:962: inode #2: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[1161508.493254] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:962: inode #2: lblock 0: comm gvfs-udisks2-vo: error -5 reading directory block
[1161547.348303] EXT4-fs (sdc1): error count since last fsck: 13
[1161547.348377] EXT4-fs (sdc1): initial error at time 1462543367: ext4_reserve_inode_write:4923
[1161547.348399] EXT4-fs (sdc1): last error at time 1506094856: ext4_find_entry:1463: inode 2
[1161560.973016] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 38 using ehci-pci
[1161562.370266] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=a200
[1161562.370270] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[1161562.370272] usb 1-1.2: Product: External USB 3.0
[1161562.370274] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
[1161562.370276] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20151217014540F
[1161562.474512] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[1161562.474797] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[1161562.523271] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=28751 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[1161562.523343] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=758130 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[1161562.533571] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=28751 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[1161562.533634] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=758130 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[1161563.823035] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[1161563.823865] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[1161564.736783] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[1161565.245948] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[1161565.245953] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[1161565.755069] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[1161567.598540]  sdd: sdd1
[1161569.239545] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 38
[1161569.290999] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[1161569.806281] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=28751 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[1161569.806324] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=758130 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[1161569.816633] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=28751 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[1161569.816671] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=758130 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[1161576.312719] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 39 using ehci-pci
[1161577.702218] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=a200
[1161577.702222] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[1161577.702224] usb 1-1.2: Product: External USB 3.0
[1161577.702226] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
[1161577.702228] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20151217014540F
[1161577.805886] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[1161577.806417] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[1161577.860971] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:4a5d:60ff:fe9a:a80d DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=28751 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
[1161579.152295] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[1161579.153207] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[1161579.670318] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[1161580.188715] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[1161580.188721] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[1161580.707054] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[1161582.573903]  sdd: sdd1
[1161585.479432] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: Even unaligned access to a 4K drive over USB1 should be faster than that. Could we get the kernel messages from when you attach it (`sudo dmesg -w` while attaching, or `journalclt -f -k`, or `tail -F /var/log/kern.log` depending on distro/version) and also `iostat -kyx /dev/sd«X» 1 5` while the copy is going (fill in the appropriate letter for the drive, e.g., `/dev/sdb`)? Also, just to confirm, how big are the files you're copying, it's not a bunch of 1-byte files, right? Please [edit] your question to include these.

Comment: @derobert: done. No iostat installed, or available on repository. Files were some MB big.

Comment: You're getting I/O errors and USB disconnects in the kernel logs. That very likely means a hardware issue. Sounds like you may have gotten a DOA unit.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check `dmesg` for errors. It is not likely, because it would cause more serious problems, but you should check.
2. You may check also the hard disk SMART parameters, if they are available throught the USB connector. You can check this with the `smartctl --all /dev/sdx`. On Debian-based distributions, it is in the `smartmontools` package, so `apt-get install smartmontools`. Also this is not likely, but possible.
3. Which is the most likely cause: USB has actually 3 sub-standards: usb1, usb2 and usb3. *Only* the usb3 gives a data throughput rate comparable with the hdds of the today.

   - Probably you plugged your disk into an usb2 compliant slot (many PCs/laptops have USB2 and USB3 compliant slots as well, for compatibility reasons). Plug into an USB3 one, or buy some USB3-friendly extension (if it is possible).
   - It is possible, that somehow the (higher bandwidth) usb3 couldn't be activated on some data noise or bad cable. And the communication between your machine and the hdd is going in some lower, slower compat modus.
   - Another possibility, that your cable or your HDD simply doesn't support USB3. Check their documentation or the internet, if they do. Another possibility to check for this, on a pure linux way: check, which usb kernel module is using your device. If it is `ehci_hcd`, then it is USB3. In the case of `ohci_hcd` or `uhci_hcd`, it is usb1 or usb2. You can get this info with the `lspci -v`, `lsusb` commands and by digging a little bit in the `/sys`.
   - Try a surely USB3-compliant cable.

The 64kbit shows an usb1 or more lower speed. USB1 is used on the todays machines only for communicating with USB mouses and keyboards.

- Didn't you plug your hard disk into an USB slot which is dedicated for keyboard/mouse? They mostly support only until USB2. It is because there are same backward compatibility problems between usb3 and usb1, and many keyboards/mouses are still usb1 only. And they don't need to be very fast.